# Substitute part of the string in a loop for a 1000 times in sh/bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a sh script that, if it is invoked by the command `./textgenerate text0`, a file `text0.txt` would be generated.

Now that I need `text0.txt`, `text1.txt`, ..., `text1000.txt`, how could I write the script to do that. i.e., how to replace the `0` part to changing variables, say 1~1000?

I know a certain "trick" to implement this, for example generate the script 1000 times using Microsoft Excel and paste it into the shell. But is there an elegent and efficient way to do this?

Comment: show your current script code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in {0..1000}; do
  ./textgenerate "text${i}"
done
```

This loops over the range [0..1,000] and assigns each value to `$i` in the body of the loop. `./textgenerate` will be invoked 1,001 times.

Comment: Bravo! Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: A C-style `for` loop would be far better; you don't need to create a list of 1,000 numbers in memory all at once: `for ((i=0; i<=1000; i++)); do`.

Comment: @chepner good point,thanks. Still, I prefer this syntax for simple tasks, and realistically if the overhead of my loop is going to be a burden on memory, perhaps Bash isn't the right tool for the job :)

Answer (score 1):

Very simply and in parallel with **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel ./textgenerate text{}.txt ::: {0..1000}
```

Or, if you don't have a recent `bash` to expand the `{0..1000}`, you could equally do this:

```
seq 0 1000 | parallel ./textgenerate text{}.txt
```

And, if you want to see what it would do, *without actually doing anything*:

```
parallel --dry-run    ... as above ...
```

And, if you want a progress bar:

```
parallel --bar  ... as above ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also let printf process the looping.

```
. <(printf "./textgenerate text%s\n" {0..1000})
```